# Perl how to kill 'rogue' thread in perl while continuing other threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm creating a perl application which executes in multiple threads and each thread consuming time. This is what I have so far

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

my @file_list = ("file1", "file2", "file3");
my @jobs;
my @failed_jobs;
my $timeout = 10; #10 seconds timeout

foreach my $s (@file_list){
    push @jobs, threads->create(sub{
        #time consuming task
    })
}

$_->join for @jobs;
```

The problem is that the time consuming task may sometimes get stuck (or take more than $timeout seconds of time to run). So when that happens, I want to get the name of the file and push it to @failed_jobs and then kill that thread. However, I want to continue with the other threads. When all threads are either killed or completed, I want to exit.

Can someone tell me how to modify my above code to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're starting all of the threads at the same time, then they'll all time out at the same time, so the situation of continuing to wait for some while others have timed out doesn't actually occur :)

Comment: Did you take the time to [Read The Fine Manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html)? Given that using Perl's interpreter threads is discouraged, you should be intimately familiar with that page and all its caveats.  The section on Thread Signalling is especially important for your question.  Voting to close as "Too Broad" since we cannot and should not duplicate the excellent existing documentation.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, The manual is silent on the issue. You can send a virtual signal, but that won't help if the process is stuck in a regex match on in an XS library. // Perl threads are discouraged only where light threads are needed. That text is misleading and in need of a patch. It's suppose to be reinforcing the previous paragraph, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ability to kill the task, you don't want threads but processes.